# how to make login script from multiple table?

Tags: php

```
> i ve got 4 separate tables to store login data.
>>> tables are  **admin_login staff_login >tutor_login student_login**.  
>>>>>> my php registration form is storing data into this fields.
```

1. now i need some suggestion how i can make login script?.
2. I've got the login form ready.

Comment: For starters why have 4 tables? Why not have 1 with a login type field??

Comment: You shouldn't be asking the question how to make the login page, but more on how to come up with the correct SQL to check your login. Retag your post with the type of DB you are using and you may get better answers

Answer (score 2):

For starters why have 4 tables? Why not have 1 with a login type field??

The general rules are the same for multiple tables as for one. You want to check for the username / email address, then check the passwords.

Start off querying your tables for the username email address. Count the results. If their is a result then check the password (with whatever if any encryption you're using) matches and log them in. If there are no results throw a message to the user saying there is no one matching that username / email, if the password doesn't match up then tell them that.

I'm not going to write it for you but here's the gist of it:

```
$query = mysql_query("CHECK FOR EMAIL ADDRESSES OR USERNAMES"); // Just query multiple tables if you're going to do it this way (I'd still use the one though)
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($count > 0) { // Email address exists
   // Check the passwords match up
   if (PASSWORDS MATCH) {
       // Do your login here
   } else {
       // Password wrong error
   }

} else {
    // No username error here
}
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is using a MYSQL DB? is that an assumption?

Comment: What help to the OP is the code, when he couldn't come up with the basic way to retrieve his data. The most important part of his question should be what you left out `"CHECK FOR EMAIL ADDRESSES OR USERNAMES"`

Comment: There's an assumed level of knowledge there I'll admit but the question is about how to build a log in script. With no table information to go on I'd say that's a fairly helpful answer.

Comment: I agree with you on that, but I think the OP has provide bit of information on both where neither is enough information to give an answer. But +1 for trying

Answer (score 0):

You could work out something using `UNION`'s but it would be better to re-factor the database to a single table with a field denoting if they are Admin/Tutor etc.

Answer (score 0):

either you can use a join query first or you can have one unified table for all users with an `accessLevel` field like:
users-table:

```
username | passwordHash | accessLevel
---------+--------------+------------
abc      |  mnbdjhgs    |   admin
pqr      |  kfgjkfbb    |   stud
```

then you can simply check userdetails you get from the loin form like:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT passwordHash, accesslevel FROM users WHERE username = '{$username}' ");

if($result)
{  $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
   if($data)
   {  if($password === $data['passwordHash'])
      {   //identify the user-type here..
          $accesslevel = $data['accessLevel'];

          //now u can do session initialization and other stuff..
      }
   }
}
else
{  //show wrong username or password messages
}
```